# can you please interpret this regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle10g, regular-language

I m new to regular expression , during learning i m confused in some basic , can you please interpret this expression

Query

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Having fun with', '([a-z])+', 'A') FROM dual;
```

Result:

```
HA A A
```

Query

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Having fun with', '([a-z])*', 'A') FROM dual;
```

Result:

```
AHAA AA AA
```

I am unable to understand main difference between + and * as per these Queries and their results.

Comment: * means any number of (i.e., zero or more), whereas + means at least one (i.e., one or more).  You should read a primer on regular expressions.

Answer (score 7):

+ - matches 1 or more lower case letters. Ex. with matches in brackets: H[aving] [fun] [with]

* - matches 0 or more lower case letters. Ex: with matches (also empty strings) in brackets: []H[aving][] [fun][] [with][]

Answer (score 2):

Not all regex engines work that way, but **Oracle regex engine will allow an empty match to follow a match of non-0-width**. However all regex engines *should* match at beginning of string.

- Using vim, with `'noignorecase'`, `:s/[a-z]*/A/g` ==> `AHA A A`.
- Using Perl, `my $in = 'Having fun with'; $in =~ s/[a-z]*/A/g;` ==> `AHAA AA AA`.

`*` is greedy and will try to match as many items as possible, just like `+`, but `*` allows 0 occurrences to match (ie, empty string).

The machine state is:

- We are at beginning of string, we have a match, the greatest length possible is 0. `H` is not matched.
- We are at position s+1, we have a match, the greatest length possible is 5 (`aving`).
- We are at position s+6, we have a match, of length 0. `<space>` is not matched.
- We are at position s+7, we have a match, of length 3 (`fun`)
- We are at position s+10, we have a match, of length 0. `<space>` is not matched.
- We are at position s+11, we have a match, of length 4 (`with`)
- We are at position s+15 (end), we still have a match of length 0.